# changing value 0/nan to max distance (urg/hokuyo node)

Tags: ros, navigation, urg-node, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to map a quite big open space but some values returned from the node is 'nan' which i suspect are areas which has no obstacle or whatsoever at max distance. How can i turn this 'nan' into a defined value so gmapping can mark it as free space?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200667/changing-value-0/nan-to-max-distance-(urg/hokuyo-node)/) by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using the `urg_node` or the `hokuyo_node`? The lasers send error codes telling what types of erroneous readings they are getting. The `urg_node` turns all error readings into NaN, but the `hokuyo_node` turns errors that are reported as "outside of max distance" into INF. Check out [this chunk of code](https://github.com/ros-drivers/hokuyo_node/blob/e8085e0fe4ff7fdc82f66311f35866af10eeaafd/src/hokuyo.cpp#L575-L636) from the `hokuyo_node` to see where they are setting INF values. Having INF values will allow you to specifically know that there are no objects in range, then you could use a [LaserScanRangeFilter](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanRangeFilter) to move all INF values to a max_range+1 value. Then you can use `~maxRange` and `~maxUrange` params in gmapping to properly handle these readings.

In summary, I've had much better luck with `hokuyo_node` than `urg_node` for specifically the reason you are describing.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2015-01-09**:
played with the filters. amazing. it's working now. thank you very much.

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2015-01-09**:
edit: i was using the urg_node before. going to use hokuyo_node from now on since it can support the old uhg-08lx

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

jarvisschultz' answer above is right, but for those who want an example, a starting point for me was changing from this

```
<launch>
<node name="pioneer_driver" pkg="p2os_driver" type="p2os_driver">
</node>
<node name="hokuyo_node" pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node">
</node>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_broadcaster" args="0.1 0 0.1397 0 0 0 1 base_link laser 100" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_broadcaster" args="0.1 0 0.1397 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />
</launch>
```

to this

```
<launch>
<node name="pioneer_driver" pkg="p2os_driver" type="p2os_driver">
</node>
<node name="hokuyo_node" pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node">
</node>
<node pkg="laser_filters" type="scan_to_scan_filter_chain" name="laser_filter">
        <rosparam command="load" file="[path]/hokuyo_config.yaml" /> 
        <remap from="base_scan" to="scan" />
</node>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_broadcaster" args="0.1 0 0.1397 0 0 0 1 base_link laser 100" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_broadcaster" args="0.1 0 0.1397 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />
</launch>
```

with `[path]/hokuyo_config.yaml` like;

```
scan_filter_chain:
- name: range
  type: LaserScanRangeFilter
  params:
    lower_threshold: 0.2
    upper_threshold: .inf
```

See  http://answers.ros.org/question/209018/using-laser_filters-to-convert-inf-readings-to-max_range-1-from-hokuyo/  and  http://answers.ros.org/question/208992/changing-value-of-nan-in-urg_node-to-max-distance/ .

---

Originally posted by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) with karma: 56 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1